# Xcode 8, iOS 10 - "Starting WebFilter logging for process"

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios10

```html
    WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Test
2016-09-30 08:56:45.458007 Test[616:142557] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2016-09-30 08:56:45.458437 Test[616:142557] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

I am receiving this warning in my debugger in xcode 8, iOS-10, when I using UIWebView Delegate methods to load something. I didn't find any documentation in Apple website about this web filter Active/De-active mode. Though it's not causing any problem in my existing webView functionality even I am running some javascript function in my webView did finished method. But still curious to know more about this new feature.

Any suggestion about this feature will be appreciate.

Comment: got any update about this?

Comment: Nope. No one replied yet.

Comment: I'm also having this. Can't find anything around the web about it...

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: I too had this problem, But in my case server giving me a wrong response so WebView is not loading

Comment: @SalehSultan Did you handle this case ?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Nope. Still I am waiting for a good answer.

Comment: In my case my web view is not loading any content i mean webViewDidStartLoad is called but then neither webViewDidFinishLoad nor didFailLoadWithError is called

Comment: @SalehSultan I am allowing unverified ssl host are you also doing anything similar.

Comment: Yes. I am doing something similar. But in another place I used 'WKWebView' to pass the authentication challenge. There it's not debugging any warning similar to this UIWebView.

Comment: Hi anyone got solution for this issues. i also struggled in this place.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

According to Apple, the "Content Security Policy(CSP)" which support in Safari 10 has been enhanced by including version 2.0 of the standard. It seems that this feature includes in `iOS 10` as well.

For more information please look here about the CSP levels: https://content-security-policy.com

OR

Check the site with Chrome Developer Tools and you will find most likely a warning like `Mixed Content: The page at '...' as loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '...'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

---

And If you want to remove the message on the XCode's console then, please find the below steps.

1. Select Product => Scheme => Edit Scheme or use shortcut : `CMD + <`
2. Select the `Run` option from left side.
3. On Environment Variables section, add the variable **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable**

For more information please find the below GIF representation.

[image: GIF]

> Note : While debug the code in device, please unchecked this option as the NSLog statement do not show in the console.

Comment: after diable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable! NSLog statement is also not showing?

Comment: you run the spplication via simulator or device.

Comment: The application run on Device

Comment: Ohk I did not check this scenario, yes in device you have to unchecked this option as the NSLog statement do not show in the console. Thanks I will update my answer.

Answer (score 15):

May be it is printing system log. Check that once and try this

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` = `disable`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to solve you have to follow the below process.
1)goto MenuBar and find product menu->Scheme->Edit Scheme->its comes up with pops ->where you select "Run" and then select "Arguments"->then Environment Variables-> after this click on "+" button and there fore put this "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable"
after that this error will gone.

Comment: What does this answer add to the previous ones?