# Xcode 8.3 libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153:

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, uiwebview, xcode8

I'm using `UIWebView` **XCode Version 8.3.** My console continues to show me this error when I start the app and I do not understand what it means.  In my `UIViewController` there is no code so I do not understand why `XCode` continues to show me this error.

I have only one place in my `webview` `viewcontroller` by `Storyboard`.

This is the error:-

> 2017-04-07 23:54:50.081592+0200 Conquers[1647:697735]
>   libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1647 (Conquers) does
>   not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and 
>    IS NOT appropriately entitled
>
> 2017-04-07 23:54:50.081651+0200 Conquers[1647:697735] libMobileGestalt
>   MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see
>   )

Comment: file a bug in bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: is this really a bug on Xcode or code issue?
I'm having the same logs when I implement `MKMapView`.

Comment: Can you show me your webview implementation. ?

Comment: Having the same error, and could not find any solution for this

Comment: Just added an answer, which cleared this up for me at this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console/44801563#44801563). The issue, in my case, turned out to be related to the need to setup a URL Scheme for Firebase.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793459/xcode-8-ios-10-starting-webfilter-logging-for-process/42385506#42385506), this might helps.

Comment: Similar issue is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console) Hope this will help u.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153 MobileGestalt.c:550 Xcode Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console)

Answer (score 1):

Just by searching on the web when I came across this issue and found that can be an Apple error (no bugs or crash are appearing with this error in my app).

If the error occurs only when you set up the UIWebView on your app. I would check if the app has configured correctly the "App transport security Settings" in your .plist

if you inspect your .plist you can add it by hand like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>add-your-site-here-if-needed</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This happens to me also when I added some third-party code like FirebaseSDK. And it suddenly stops appearing after I setup correctly my URL schemes for all my environments. So I´m assuming that this error appears when something is not fully/correctly implemented like in a snowball effect by Apple side code.

NOTE: You can also try to go back a few steps back on when the error occurs to narrow down the possibilities of occurrences of this error.