# stop video from auto playing swift UI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, youtube, video-player

Hello I a have some code that loads a web video into a swift ui view and allows it to be played. Currently the video auto plays when it loads in and I would like to stop this behavior. Additionally the video can only be viewed in full screen mode and I can't figure out how to make it so that it can play while not being in full screen. I also get the warning "Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement" I tried the line "webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true" to allow the video to play while not being full sized and it did not work. If anyone knows how to get these 2 pieces of functionality working I would appreciate it, thanks.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let videoId: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
          let webView = WKWebView()
          webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
            
          webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
          
          return webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let demoURL = URL(string: "https://s1.fwmrm.net/m/1/169843/20/89977492/AIDP7266000H_ENT_MEZZ_HULU_8166176_578.mp4") else { return }
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.load(URLRequest(url: demoURL))
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var ids = "hzls6ZUHCYM"
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    YouTubeView(videoId: ids)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 175)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//modifier correct YouTube struct
struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoID: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let embedHTML = """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <iframe width="800" height="550" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </body>
            </html>
        """
        uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try loading your video embedded within html rather than directly to an mp4 url. set the `playsinline` parameter for the `video` tag. also set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` prior to instantiating the `WKWebView` object.

as for the entitlement error, [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313219/3680644) seem to indicate that this can simply be ignored.

```
let html = """
    <video
    src="https://s1.fwmrm.net/m/1/169843/20/89977492/AIDP7266000H_ENT_MEZZ_HULU_8166176_578.mp4"
    width="640" height="480"
    controls
    playsinline="true">
"""

struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true //set up config first
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil) //load video embedded inside html
    }
}
```

Comment: one question, when I pass in a YouTube videos url into the html, the video Is not able to play and displays a dash through the unpause button. However with my original code It does, what can I do to make a YouTube video play with your modifications?

Comment: nvm I figured it out, all I had to do was simply change the html and use Iframe, I will update my code above for anyone interested to see.

Comment: Fault maybe you can help with this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76360300/remove-white-background-border-from-swift-video-rendered-using-embedded-html-and

Comment: can you please look at this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624877/swift-long-press-gesture-only-works-on-link-and-not-on-text-portion