# remove white background/border from swift video rendered using embedded HTML and WKWebView

Tags: html, swift, swiftui, youtube-api

Hello I have a YouTube struct that loads in YouTube shorts and the videos have a large white background or border around them and I can't get it to go away. I tried applying .tint, .foreground, .background and none work. The only way of changing the size of the white border is by changing the width and height inside the embedded HTML. It seems like the video doesn't fill the whole frame so a white border fills the rest. If anyone knows how I can modify this code to get ride of the white border Id appreciate it. I am also facing an issue where the YouTube play/pause button along with the time bar and all the other video options are very small and don't increase with the size of the video.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            YouTubeView(link: "-rHELEJuqkU")               
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}

struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
     
        let embedHTML = """
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
                    <iframe width="500" height="920" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(link)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            """
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's hard to specify the size of the youtube controls, you could scale the entire view up like this

```
YouTubeView(link: "-rHELEJuqkU")
   .scaleEffect(3, anchor: .topLeading)
```

then adjust your html code accordingly

```
let embedHTML = """
<body style="background-color:black;">
    <iframe
    width="315"
    height="560"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(link)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
"""
```

it's not pixel perfect since the size and aspect ratio of the video will not match the size and aspect ratio of the iOS device.. but it's pretty close.

Comment: Thanks, scale effect does in fact increase the size of the option buttons!