# Use TrinityPlayer SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I would like to use 'TrinityAudioSDK'. However I got the below error message.

"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file AudioSample/CustomView.swift, line 33
2021-03-29 15:09:27.880854+0900 AudioSample[8735:3351247] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file AudioSample/CustomView.swift, line 33"

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import TrinityPlayer


class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var customView: CustomView!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
        
    }
    
}
```

```
import UIKit
import TrinityPlayer

class CustomView : UIView {
    
    let TAInstance = TrinityAudio.newInstance()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var audioView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.comonInit()
    }
    
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         self.comonInit()
     }
    
    func comonInit() {
        
        if (audioView == nil){
            print("not working")
        }

        TAInstance.render(parentViewController: MainViewController(), unitId: "testest", sourceView: audioView, fabViewTopLeftCoordinates: nil, contentURL: URL(string: "https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-56559904")!, settings: ["language":"en"])
    }
    
}
```

Do you have any ideas to solve it?

V/r,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a nil for your custom view because you are trying to access it before the view hierarchy is loaded. At the time of `init()` your `customView` is not yet available. To solve this issue you can just put your `commonInit` to  `awakeFromNib`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    comonInit()
}
```

Comment: I checked it. It is connected.

Comment: Could you please double check the IBOutlet for the audioView in your CustomView. Also sometimes deleting the IBOutlet, cleaning the project and reconnecting it helps.

Comment: Yes I checked it and did that you said. It doesn't solve.

Comment: Could you please try to remove the weak from `@IBOutlet weak var audioView: UIView!` just to make sure you do not have a nil there ?

Comment: I removed it. And I put the IBOutlet again. But I got the nil from CustomView adn audioView.

Comment: I got error the message "Instance member 'comonInit' cannot be used on type 'CustomView"

Comment: @MasayaStripes it is the `class` keyword that's causing the error. If you remove it it will work. See my update also.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I got these error message here.
2021-04-05 13:41:52.053523+0900 AudioSample[1299:13177806] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process AudioSample
2021-04-05 13:41:52.053779+0900 AudioSample[1299:13177806] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2021-04-05 13:41:52.053975+0900 AudioSample[1299:13177806] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

Comment: It seems it's an other issue. Try to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793459/xcode-8-ios-10-starting-webfilter-logging-for-process